# The API response is returning unasked for properties

Tags: bug, api

The request

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/186134?site=askubuntu&filter=!40Cbi5zuVlXG1TB2N
```

does not have the `sort=reputation` or `order=desc` parameters.  It also does not have reputation specified in the filter. Sometimes it returns this:

```
{"items":[{"badge_counts":{"bronze":94,"silver":50,"gold":9}}]}
```

as expected.

But, other times it returns this:

```
{"items":[{"badge_counts":{"bronze":94,"silver":50,"gold":9},"reputation":13804,"user_id":186134}]}
```

with unasked-for properties `reputation` and `user_id`.

Why? Could this be made consistent?

Comment: @Awesome I wouldn't say that they were / weren't asked for, as they're not part of the filter (tbh I'd expect them all the time). But it certainly shouldn't be a whimsical thing. Also I worry if they always return the second thing when you do include, as I'm now using that data.

Comment: Your comment is not clear.  Are you saying that you now *want* `reputation`?  As for "unasked for", you explicitly removed those fields from the filter. So that seems to be concise language to describe the problem.  "Rejected" might be more appropriate -- depending on your intention.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles But those things are separate from the `&filter!=` section (and cannot be changed within that filter - suggesting they should always be there. Maybe adding / removing is akin to saying get / don't get). I'm saying I don't mind if it gives it or not (not is probably better).

Comment: Two things (normally) control whether you get a field: (1) is it specified in the filter, (2) is it used in the results sort.  Since `reputation` is neither in your case, it is "Unasked for" at best, or "Rejected" at worst. If you don't care if it gives it, just ignore it for now (it will still be a bug).  If you always want it, add it to the filter. ... Edit your question if you wish and it makes it clearer but the old title was way too generic.